# Can not set ephemeral.volumeClaimTemplate name

Tags: kubernetes, ephemeral-storage

I wanted to set a name for ephemeral volumeClaimTemplate but it didn't work.

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: test-job
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: test
            image: my-image:dev
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            command: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: "/export"
                name: export-dir
          volumes:
            - name: export-dir
              ephemeral:
                volumeClaimTemplate:
                  metadata:
                    name: test-pvc
                  spec:
                    accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
                    storageClassName: "do-block-storage-wait"
                    resources:
                      requests:
                        storage: 100Gi
```

which produces these errors:

- spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.volumes[0].ephemeral.volumeClaimTemplate.metadata.name: Forbidden: cannot be set
- spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "export-dir"

Comment: Name field in **volumeClaimTemplate** is not allowed,  try removing it from the manifest.

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful, if it was helpful I will post it as an answer for greater visibility for the community.

Comment: Yes @KapilSakhare, remove that name worked but I want to set a name. Seems there is no way for `volumeClaimTemplate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name field in **volumeClaimTemplate** is not allowed,that is why it is showing **“spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.volumes[0].ephemeral.volumeClaimTemplate.metadata.name: Forbidden: cannot be set”** error.

In your config file you have set the name explicitly which is forbidden, try removing it from the **ephemeral** section. It may help to resolve the issue.

Refer to this [Ephemeral volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/ephemeral-volumes/)  doc for more information.